# How do I set the default number of digits shown in PySpark?

Tags: pyspark

I'd like to see only n digits (e.g., 3) of the floating point numbers in PySpark. Is there a way to set the default? Note that I don't want to round the actual data.

The followings show what I have and it is too much info:

```
>>> df = sc.parallelize( [ ('a', 1), ('b', 2) ] ).toDF()
>>> df.withColumn("x", rand()).show()
+---+---+------------------+
| _1| _2|                 x|
+---+---+------------------+
|  a|  1|0.7468471761178085|
|  b|  2|0.6189219219244186|
+---+---+------------------+
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it's only for display, you can use pandas and specify a float format:

```py
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format
df = sc.parallelize( [ ('a', 1), ('b', 2) ] ).toDF()
df.withColumn("x", rand()).limit(20).toPandas()
```